# how to use TransportAPI to generate a route at a specified time?

Tags: r, geolocation, rstudio

I was using [TransportAPI](https://developer.transportapi.com/docs?raml=https://transportapi.com/v3/raml/transportapi.raml##request_uk_public_journey_from_from_to_to_type_date_time_json) to request a public route that took place at a specified date and time.

But it didnt return any route data. How should I set the date and time?

Answer (score 2):

There's two different TransportAPI endpoints which you might be referring to when you say "public route" here. In both cases you can add date and time to the query:

You might mean "bus/route" - bus timetable information about one particular route. You actually have to specify a bus route (operator and line name) and details of particular departure, so for example here is the 185 bus departure at 11:26 today towards Lewisham: 
http://transportapi.com/v3/uk/bus/route/LONDONBUS/185/inbound/490012571T/2017-09-22/11:26/timetable.json?app_id=***APP_ID***&app_key=***APP_KEY***

...or you might mean "public/journey". A route (or "journey plan") through the public transport system from one location to another. For example here's a journey plan from Vauxhall to Bethnal Green. The response is not just one route, but multiple alternatives

https://transportapi.com/v3/uk/public/journey/from/lonlat:-0.11966,51.48626/to/lonlat:-0.05703,51.52398/at/2017-10-10/10:00.json?
app_id=***APP_ID***&app_key=***APP_KEY***

The `/at/2017-10-10/10:00` bit specifies your desired departure time, but you can also say `/by/2017-10-10/10:00` to specify a desired arrival time, or you can leave it out (then it just plans for departing now)